# 2D wave equation is numerically unstable using Finite Difference Method

Tags: pde, finite-difference, simulation, stability

I'm working with simulating both the heat and wave equation in 2D in a Python code. When simulating the heat equation, I learned about the CFL which I used to get a numerical stable solution.

I found CFL for the 2D wave equation as well, but my solution keeps being numerically unstable no matter how I change the time increments $dt$. I'm presenting the code here:

```py
# Libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib as mpl



def f(X,Y): # f(x,y,0)
    return X**2+Y**2

def g(X,Y): # g(x,y,0)
    return X

def laplacian(arr, row,col, dx ):
    return (arr[row + 1, col]
                            + arr[row - 1, col] + arr[row, col + 1]
                            + arr[row, col - 1]- 4*arr[row,col])/(dx**2)

def simulation(rect,hs,BC, c, frames, eq, eps = 1e-10):

    """ Simulation of the heat equation on a
    2D rectangular grid using the Finite Difference Method """

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(rect[0],rect[1],hs[0]),
                       np.linspace(rect[2],rect[3],hs[1])) # 2D meshgrid

    # Initial Conditions
    Z_init = f(X,Y) # u(x,y,0) = f(x,y,0)
    Z_dot_init = g(X,Y) # u_t(x,y,0) = g(x,y,0)

    zmax = max(Z_init.max(), BC[0], BC[1], BC[2], BC[3])
    zmin = min(Z_init.min(), BC[0], BC[1], BC[2], BC[3])
    zs = [Z_init]

    # Boundary Conditions
    if eq == "Heat":
        Z_init[0] = np.ones(len(Z_init[0])) * BC[0]
        Z_init[-1] = np.ones(len(Z_init[-1]))* BC[1]
        Z_init[:,0] =  np.ones(len(Z_init[:,0]))* BC[2]
        Z_init[:, -1] = np.ones(len(Z_init[:, -1])) * BC[3]

    # Figure settings
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.axes.set_xlim3d(rect[0] + eps, rect[1] - eps)
    ax.axes.set_ylim3d(rect[2] + eps, rect[3] - eps)
    ax.axes.set_zlim3d(zmin, zmax)
    plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'
    plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'STIXGeneral'

    # Plots for lines constituting the rectangle
    ax.plot([rect[0], rect[1]], [rect[2], rect[2]], [BC[0], BC[0]], color='black', linewidth=2)
    ax.plot([rect[1], rect[1]], [rect[2], rect[3]], [BC[3], BC[3]], color='black', linewidth=2)
    ax.plot([rect[0], rect[0]], [rect[2], rect[3]], [BC[2], BC[2]], color='black', linewidth=2)
    ax.plot([rect[0], rect[1]], [rect[3], rect[3]], [BC[1], BC[1]], color='black', linewidth=2)

    ax.plot([rect[0], rect[0]], [rect[2], rect[2]], [BC[0], BC[2]], color='black', linewidth=2)
    ax.plot([rect[1], rect[1]], [rect[2], rect[2]], [BC[0], BC[3]], color='black', linewidth=2)
    ax.plot([rect[0], rect[0]], [rect[3], rect[3]], [BC[1], BC[2]], color='black', linewidth=2)
    ax.plot([rect[1], rect[1]], [rect[3], rect[3]], [BC[1], BC[3]], color='black', linewidth=2)
    ax.set_title('Temperature development in a \n'
                 'rectangular room', fontsize = 18, fontname = 'STIXGeneral')

    # Infitesimals
    dx = (rect[1] - rect[0]) / ((hs[0] - 1))
    if eq == 'Heat':
        dt = dx**2/(10*c**2)
    else:
        dt = dx/(10*c)

    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z_init, alpha=0.7, cmap=plt.cm.jet, vmin=zmin, vmax=zmax)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(surf)
    cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Temperature in ' + r'$^\circ\mathrm{C}$', rotation=270,fontsize = 14, labelpad=20)
    ax.set_axis_off()


    # Finite Difference Method
    if eq == 'Wave':

        for row in range(1, hs[0] - 1):
            for col in range(1, hs[1] - 1):
                Z_init[row,col] = Z_init[row,col] - 2 * laplacian(Z_dot_init,row,col, dx) + 1/2 * c ** 2 * dt ** 2 / (
                    dx) ** 2 * (Z_init[row+1, col] - 4 * Z_init[row, col]
                                + Z_init[row-1, col] + Z_init[row, col+1]
                                + Z_init[row, col-1])

        zs.append(Z_init)

        for iteration in range(2,frames):
            surf.remove()
            for row in range(1, hs[0]-1):
                for col in range(1,hs[1]-1):
                    Z_init[row,col] += 2 * zs[iteration - 1][row, col] - zs[iteration - 2][row, col] + c ** 2 * dt ** 2 / (
                            dx**2) * (zs[iteration - 1][row + 1, col] - 4 * zs[iteration - 1][row, col]
                                        + zs[iteration - 1][row - 1, col] + zs[iteration - 1][row, col + 1]
                                        + zs[iteration - 1][row, col - 1])

            zs.append(Z_init)
            surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, zs[iteration-2], alpha = 0.7, cmap =plt.cm.jet, vmin = zmin, vmax = zmax)
            plt.pause(dt * 10)

    if eq == 'Heat':

        for iteration in range(frames):

            surf.remove()
            for row in range(1, hs[0]-1):
                for col in range(1,hs[1]-1):
                    Z_init[row,col] = Z_init[row,col] + c**2 * dt / (dx)**2  *(Z_init[row+1,col] - 4*Z_init[row,col]
                                                   + Z_init[row-1,col] + Z_init[row,col+1]
                                                   + Z_init[row,col-1])

            # Plotting surface with slight pause
            surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z_init, alpha = 0.7, cmap =plt.cm.jet, vmin = zmin, vmax = zmax)
            plt.pause(dt)

simulation(rect = [-1,1,-1,1], hs = [100,100], BC = [0,0,0,0], c = 3, frames = 1000, eq = 'Wave')
```

I'm adding an image of the user instructions too:

[image]

Either way, I've tried searching for how to make my code numerically stable, but with no results. I tried changing the time steps to be even lower, I tried adding more elements into the grid, tried changing the maximum velcity, tried changing the initial conditions. I even tried removing the boundary conditions to only apply for the heat equation.

If you have any ideas on how to help me solve this, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are your boundary conditions? How are you computing your Courant number?

Comment: @nicoguaro My boundary conditions are given by the array BC, in this case, all boundary conditions are 0 meaning that the wave always is 0 at the boundaries. I compute my Courant number as $dt = K * dx/(v_{max})$ and choosing $K<1$ and $v_{max} = c$. See "infitesimals" in my code.

Comment: Big error: You overwrite the old values with the new values and then use the new values to update later new values. I'm not sure if that is sufficient to destabilize the solution process, but it will lead to a wrong dynamic.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Wow thank you really! I have a question though regarding this, if I for instance make a list with an array that I later on change in a loop will this change go through to the array although it's "inside" the array in Python? Either way, I managed to solve it my just creating a temporary array. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  You can reduce the temporary memory to just 3 or 2 rows that would indeed be used in a loop. You can use slicing operations to employ the internal C loops of numpy, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75244700/3088138. You could also use the numpy convolution operation along the rows (and perhaps also the columns, depending on the strategy).

Comment: Another variant that gives not exactly the same method but is correct of the same order is to organize two sweeps in a checkerboard, red-blue, leapfrog pattern. So in a first sweep you update all red/white fields and in a second all blue/black fields. This gives something like a combination of a forward and a backward Euler step.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Very interesting! Do you know the specific name of this "method". I tried looking for it but couldn't find something.

Comment: I thought that "checkerboard" or "chessboard" was a used name for such methods, seems to be wrong. Leapfrog is used, but more to advance the two half-grids alternatingly by two time steps, with the other half-grid in the middle providing the derivative. One can be relatively free with such constructions for first-order methods. If everything is as symmetric as possible, usually the method will turn out to have second order.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks! I found many hits when searching for "Leapfrog Method". Seems like something that's prefered over the FDM when simulating the wave eqn.   I'll check that out and try to implement in my code :) Btw, you can post your first comment as an answer and I'll accept it for you.